# How do I use oozie java action with a war file

Tags: java, war, oozie

I have a java class file inside a regular .war. Is it possible to use this war file with a java action in oozie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this, because you need to have your class in classpath, and WAR file cannot be added to class path as is.